# Bash Script - tail to file

Tags: bash

I have the following in a bash script file watcher.sh.

```
grep ERROR $ExampleLogFile > $ErrorLogFile
```

When I run this, it copied the lines from ExampleLogFile to ErrorLogFile that contain `ERROR` successfully.

I need to make it so it continually monitors the ExampleLogFile for changes and writes those to the ErrorLogFile.

I was thinking of doing the following, but this doesn't work:

```
tail -f grep ERROR $ExampleLogFile > $ErrorLogFile
```

It does write some of the lines, but its not the ones containing `ERROR`.

> ```
> tail: grep: No such file or directory
> tail: ERROR: No such file or directory
> ```

Any advise please.

Comment: tail expects files as arguments, you need pipes to use grep and tail together. See @Don't Panic answer.

Comment: When you are using log4j, you can configure writing errors to both the normal log and `$ErrorLogFile`. Can you avoid the tail with a solution like this?

Comment: maybe have a look at [watch command](https://linuxize.com/post/linux-watch-command/) or [inotify](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
while :; do grep ERROR $ExampleLogFile > $ErrorLogFile; sleep 2; done
```

This should achieve what you want without needing the tail command.

If the file will ever be cleared though this will not work as you might expect because the grep will pull only current entries in the $ErrorLogFile.

Comment: Depending on the size of the log file, and system load, this can take some time. Also, note that there will be period when the ErrorLogFile will be empty/partial. If you take this route, consider preparing running the grep into temporary file (same folder), and renaming the final after the grep to achieve continuity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tee` command here.

```
tail -f $ExampleLogFile | grep --line-buffered  ERROR | tee $ErrorLogFile
```

It will store and print to stdout at the same time.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this executes, copying the correct lines, but then the task finishes. I need it to continually run, and copy any new lines that come into the `ExampleLogFile`.

Comment: @user2569831 Try this: watch $(tail -f <(grep ERROR $ExampleLogFile | tee $ErrorLogFile))

Comment: Thanks @Max, but I get the following errors:  `line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `('` and `line 16: 'tail -f <(grep ERROR $ExampleLogFile | tee $ErrorLogFile)'`

Comment: @user2569831 It works for me on macOS and centOS. What version of bash are you using?

Comment: MacOS BASH_VERSION 3.2.57(1)-release.  I am running it from a sh file

Comment: check the updated answer. It will work for the stream buffer.

Comment: @user2569831 You don't seem to have typed out the command I offered correctly checking your error message again. It's: watch $(tail -f <(grep ERROR $ExampleLogFile | tee $ErrorLogFile))

Comment: @AkhilJalagam, with your new solution, I get: `log_watcher.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `('
log_watcher.sh: line 16: `tail -f <(grep ERROR $ExampleLogFile | tee $ErrorLogFile) '`.

Comment: @Max, I get:  `log_watcher.sh: command substitution: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `('
log_watcher.sh: command substitution: line 17: `tail -f <(grep ERROR $ExampleLogFile | tee $ErrorLogFile)'
log_watcher.sh: line 17: watch: command not found`.

Comment: @user2569831 thanks, interesting. Try this " while :; do grep ERROR $ExampleLogFile >> $ErrorLogFile; sleep 2; done " no tail needed

Comment: @AkhilJalagam. I kind of get your solution working (using `tee`). It does write continually as expected, but it doesn't write the last line in the error file, and writes all the data again (duplicates) each time the error file is saved.

Comment: That's not possible.It shouldn't write duplicates unless you are calling it multiple times.screenshot showing it.

Comment: @Max, that works `while :; do grep ERROR $ExampleLogFile >> $ErrorLogFile; sleep 2; done`.  But it is getting duplicates.  Each time I view the `ErrorLogFile`, it writes all the ERRORS again.

Comment: @user2569831 I'll write a proper answer to your question rather than in comments now

Comment: @AkhilJalagam, each time I save the `ExampleLogFile`, it writes all the errors again to the `ErrorLogFile`. (except it never writes the very last line for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange the tail/grep in a pipe

```
tail -f $ExampleLogFile | grep ERROR  > $ErrorLogFile
```

Remember that this command will never exit by itself (tail will continue to look for additional data). You will have to arrange for some other exit condition (e.g., timeout, explicit kill, etc).

Comment: No results will be outputted to $ErrorLogFile -- Make a script called watcher.sh, run it in the background and then echo ERROR (append) to $ExampleLogFile and you'll see it doesn't work

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. When I run it, it does not copy anything to the `ErrorLogFile`. It is running because the terminal shows any `echo` messages, and it can be terminated with CTL+C.

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -f $ExampleLogFile | grep --line-buffered ERROR > $ErrorLogFile
```

or paranoic:

```
stdbuf -oL tail -f $ExampleLogFile | stdbuf -oL grep --line-buffered ERROR > $ErrorLogFile
```

But most probably you want to include existing lines too. In that case:

```
tail -n +1 -f $ExampleLogFile | grep --line-buffered ERROR > $ErrorLogFile
```

Comment: Nice, I learned something today. Can you explain why `--line-buffered` is required? (BTW I upvoted, not sure who downvoted or why).

Comment: Well, because the output is fully buffered by `grep` when outputting to a file. From other answers I deduced that OP wants to see output in "realtime" in the output file, so I guess `line-buffered` is a must. For quick test see for example `{ seq 40; sleep 1; } | grep 3 | cat` vs. `{ seq 40; sleep 1; } | grep --line-buffered 3 | cat`